# UI not updating time even timer are in different threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, task

I'm starting two timers in different threads (one is running 20 secs and the other one for 1 sec).
If the 1 second timer elapsed, the property "Time" is updated. This property is the binding for a label. 
The property is updated correctly but the UI only updates every few seconds.

Here is the code for the timers:

```
    public void InitializeAlarm()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 20000;// 21600000
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            this.Time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
            timer.Start();
        });

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var timerForCountDown = new Timer();
            timerForCountDown.Interval = 1000;// 21600000
            timerForCountDown.Enabled = true;
            timerForCountDown.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(UpdateCountDown);
            timerForCountDown.AutoReset = true;
            timerForCountDown.Start();
        });

    }

    private void UpdateCountDown(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Time = this.Time.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
    }

    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Do some stuff
    }
```

And thats the binding:

`<Label Content="{Binding Time}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="15"/>`

Comment: You cannot update the UI from another thread directly. You must invoke a control. See: [WPF Dispatcher - Introduction and How to use?](http://dotnetpattern.com/wpf-dispatcher).

Comment: Thanks, is there any "fake" invoke that will solve my problem?

Comment: Starting a Timer in a Task is pointless, as it already runs on a ThreadPool thread. That said, you should not use System.Timers.Timer at all in a WPF application. Just create and start as many DispatcherTimers as necessary on the UI thread. Their Tick handlers are already invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Another point is: Does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `Time` property raise the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

I have created both a stopwatch and timer in WPF before, and I found this solution to be the easiest I tried.

Instead of using different threads, just create two DispatchTimers. Then you can bind your second variable to the label like so:

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged; make sure you have your seconds variable;

```
    private int _Seconds
    public int Seconds
    {
        get
        {
            return _Seconds;
        }
        set
        {
            _Seconds = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Seconds)));
            }
        }

    }
```

and add the binding to your label in the xaml

```
    Text="{Binding Seconds, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```